# How to fix 'Notice: Undefined index:' in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I have an error and I don't know how to fix it.

The error is:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 0 in ... on line 94

Here's the line that causes the error:

```
$this->html = str_replace ($parts['0'], stripslashes($return), $this->html);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try $parts[0], but without knowing what the variable $parts contains noone can give you an answer.

Comment: Is $parts an array and has a key 0? The error says $parts does not have any element with the jey 0 you can use isset function to check

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this notice shows up when you try to access an `array` key that does not exist.
you can prevent this notice (before calling an array key) using the `isset` function and check if the key is present.

```
if( isset( $myArray['key'] ) ) {
    // key present
}
```

Comment: Ist works :) Thank you very much, I had more problems at my server with if{}, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This suggests that `$parts['0']` doesn't have a value in it.

It is almost certainly a logic issue in your code.

Do you actually mean `$parts['0']`, or should it be `$parts[0]`.  That would be more normal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print_r($parts)` to check what the array actually contains.